# How to include <sys/select.h> library in a Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am a beginner with Visual Studio and now I want to run a C++ program on it, but when I compile the program  there is an error that `<sys/select.h>` is not defined.

So, how can I define it or include it in the project?

Comment: "sys/select.h" is UNIX header. You need to find the Windows equivalent and you can include it without any problems.

Comment: The equivalent for windows is [WinSock2.h](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: did you get the solution for this, ?? i'm in a similar situation now

Answer (score 7):

`sys/select.h` is a POSIX header that supports `select()`; the [equivalent on Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only works on sockets, so you are unlikely to get the code working on Windows unless you are already skilled at porting.

Comment: the point is i am not using sockets but i have a code now for a profram and my task is to modify in some classes on it not the whole project so i am not dealing with this header file or select() but it has to be defined just for running the whole project but i won't deal with this part of the project

Answer (score 3):

The header files (which are not libraries) in the sys directory are system specific - you can't just take code that uses them and works on one platform and compile it on another one. And note that there may very well be no equivalent on the target platform - you may well have to rewrite the code that depends on sys headers.

Comment: the point is i am not using sockets but i have a code now for a program and my task is to modify in some classes on it not the whole project so i am not dealing with this header file but it has to be defined just for running the whole project but i won't deal with this part of the project

Comment: @fank If the code isn't using sockets, then you probably don't need the header file - just remove the #include.

Comment: i am not using sockets or i can say there are sockets in the program but i am not working on it , my work is in another part of the project but i have to define them to be able to run the whole project

Comment: Just because the code isn't using sockets doesn't mean it isn't using `select`. A common usage of `select` is `select(0,NULL,NULL,NULL,&sleep_interval)`, where `sleep_interval` specifies the time interval for which the application is to sleep.